# How to get twig variable after ajax call

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, twig

I use nodejs to do a personal project (and learn nodejs).
For the view I use twig.
In my index.html.twig I have a block which load a twig template. This is a list that displays all rows of my database.

```
<div id="table">
        {% include 'liste.html.twig' %}
</div>
```

In this template I  have a variable called "segment"

```
{% for key, s in segment|slice(0, 10)  %}
            ...
{% endfor %}
```

I did a pagination system to displays only 10 rows => it work

```
let up = document.getElementById('up');
        let pageA = 1
        var segments = {{ segment|json_encode()|raw }}
        up.addEventListener('click', function(){
            let tbody = document.getElementById("tbody")
            tbody.innerHTML = ""
            pageA++;
            
            for(let i=(pageA-1)*10;i<pageA*10;i++){
               let dist = segments[i]['distance']/1000
               tbody.innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+segments[i]['name']+"</td><td>"+segments[i]['nbSegment']+"</td><td>"+dist.toFixed(2)+"km</td><td>"+segments[i]['total_elevation_gain']+"m</td><td>"+segments[i]['average_grade']+"%</td><tr>"
            }
            addRowHandlers();
        })
```

I have also a field to do a specific research. To do that I used ajax and reload only this block => It work also. My table displays 10 first results of my research

```
app.get('/search', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {  
   req.query.page = 1
   getSegmentsByNameDb(escapeHtml(req.query.name)).then(value => {
     res.render('liste.html.twig', {segment:value})
   })
 });
```

My problem is that I can't get the new twig variable "segment" after the research and so my pagination doesn't work.
When I do a console.log(segment) it displays all the rows of the DB and not only the rows of the research.

Why the twig variable segment is not reset when my template liste.html.twig is reload ?

Comment: Cause the template is rendered serverside?

Comment: Hello @DarkBee, thanks for your answer. Yes, so it's impossible to do that I want ? Why when I load the first time, i can get the variable twig and not when I load only the liste.html.twig ?